# Duplicated value in item of ListView when scrolldown

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have an increasing button in listview OnClickListener() of this button in item increase number in show it in testview the problem is when i scrolldown anther item in the listview changes to the same number that increased.

This is My Adpater

```
public class ProductsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<ProductSubModel> myList;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
int i;

public ProductsAdapter(Context context, List<ProductSubModel> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return myList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    final MyViewHolder mViewHolder;
    i = 0;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_product, viewGroup, false);
        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    mViewHolder.productImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(myList.get(position).getImage())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.nadarah_icon)
            .override(250, 250)
            .into(mViewHolder.productImageView);

    mViewHolder.productNameTextView.setText(myList.get(position).getProductName());
    mViewHolder.productDescribtionTextView.setText("DESC : " + myList.get(position).getShortDescription());
    mViewHolder.productPriceTextView.setText("PRISE : " + myList.get(position).getPrice());
    mViewHolder.discountPriceTextView.setText("DISCOUNT : " + myList.get(position).getMinimalPrice());
    mViewHolder.qtyFromApiTextView.setText("QTY : " + 20);
    mViewHolder.minusImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (i > 0) {
                i--;
                mViewHolder.qtyUserBuyTextView.setText("" + i);
            } else {
                Utils.msg(context , "");
            }
        }
    });
    mViewHolder.plusImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (i < 20) {
                i++;
                mViewHolder.qtyUserBuyTextView.setText("" + i);
            } else {
                Utils.msg(context , "");
            }
        }
    });
    mViewHolder.addtoCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}


private class MyViewHolder {
    ImageView productImageView;
    TextView productNameTextView;
    TextView productDescribtionTextView;
    TextView productPriceTextView;
    TextView discountPriceTextView;
    TextView qtyFromApiTextView;
    ImageView minusImageView;
    ImageView plusImageView;
    TextView qtyUserBuyTextView;
    TextView addtoCartButton;
    TextView productIdTextView;


    public MyViewHolder(View item) {
        productImageView = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.productImageView);
        productNameTextView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.productNameTextView);
        productDescribtionTextView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.productDescribtionTextView);
        productPriceTextView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.productPriceTextView);
        discountPriceTextView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.discountPriceTextView);
        qtyFromApiTextView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.qtyFromApiTextView);
        minusImageView = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.minusImageView);
        qtyUserBuyTextView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.qtyUserBuyTextView);
        plusImageView = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.plusImageView);
        addtoCartButton = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.addtoCartButton);
        productIdTextView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.productIdTextView);
    }

}
}
```

This is adapter implementation

```
private void implementAdpater(List<ProductSubModel> productSubModels) {
    this.productSubModels = productSubModels;
    productsAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(getActivity(), productSubModels);
    productsInCategoryList.setAdapter(productsAdapter);
    productsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a field in ProductSubModel of Quantity (or whatever is increasing or decreasing), and each time you increment also increment in model.

```
i++;
mViewHolder.qtyUserBuyTextView.setText("" + i);
myList.get(position).setQunatity(myList.get(position).getQunatity()+1);
```

Outside from the listener

```
mViewHolder.qtyUserBuyTextView.setText("" + myList.get(position).getQunatity());
```

same for decrement

Answer (score 1):

Remove the productsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after setadapter() and check it once.

check this for your reference :
http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial